# How can I improve this POSTGRES (SQL) query by reducing the selects and joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure there is a better syntactical way of doing the below, in that, doing the following is enough to achieve the desired result but I'd like to do it with an appropriate syntax and possibly remove/reduce the unnecessary joins and selects on the same tables.

(ie. The fields rg.NAME and T.NAME are used more than once)

```
INSERT INTO BSHIP (ID, IS_ID, C_ID, A_A_ID, A_A_INSTID, P_ID)
         SOME_ID,
        (SELECT t.IS_ID FROM T t LEFT OUTER JOIN BSHIP ON T.IS_ID=BSHIP.IS_ID WHERE T.NAME='XYZ'),
        (SELECT t.id FROM T t LEFT OUTER JOIN BSHIP ON T.IS_ID=BSHIP.IS_ID WHERE T.NAME='XYZ'), 
        (SELECT rg.objbshps_id FROM RT_GP rg LEFT OUTER JOIN T ON rg.IS_ID=T.IS_ID WHERE T.NAME='XYZ' AND rg.NAME='ABC'), 
        (SELECT t.IS_ID FROM T t LEFT OUTER JOIN BSHIP ON T.IS_ID=BSHIP.IS_ID WHERE T.NAME='XYZ'), 
        (SELECT rg.id FROM RT_GP rg LEFT OUTER JOIN T ON rg.IS_ID=T.IS_ID WHERE T.NAME='XYZ' AND rg.NAME='ABC'), 
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Assuming this is doing what you want (I don't know what you want) it looks fine. No reason to think this performs badly provided you have an index on T.Name and BSHIP.IS_ID.

Comment: If it is performing badly do `EXPLAIN(analyze, timing, costs, verbose, format json)` and post it in PEV (http://tatiyants.com/pev/) to see why.

Comment: Haven't been writing SQL for a while so was just wondering if there is a cleaner or short-hand way of writing it, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO BSHIP (ID, IS_ID, C_ID, A_A_ID, A_A_INSTID, P_ID)
    SELECT SOME_ID, t.IS_ID, t_id
           (SELECT rg.objbshps_id FROM RT_GP rg 
WHERE rg.IS_ID = T.IS_ID AND rg.NAME = 'ABC'), 
           t.IS_ID, 
           (SELECT rg.id FROM RT_GP rg WHERE rg.IS_ID = T.IS_ID AND rg.NAME = 'ABC')
    FROM t 
    WHERE t.NAME = 'XYZ'
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and is a bit cleaner.

```
INSERT INTO BSHIP (ID, IS_ID, C_ID, A_A_ID, A_A_INSTID, P_ID)
    SOME_ID, t.IS_ID, t_id, rg.objbshps_id, t.IS_ID, rg.ID 
    FROM t, RT_GP rg
    WHERE t.NAME = 'XYZ' 
    AND rg.NAME = 'ABC'
    AND rg.IS_ID = T.IS_ID
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```